# How to set parent element of xml while returning a hashmap

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am building a LinkedHashMap and putting key value pairs in it.

I am returning this hashmap as follows

```
return new ResponseEntity(LinkedHashMapObject, httpStatus.OK)
```

I am getting the following output

```
<LinkedHashMap>
     <flightnumber>001</flightnumber>
     <Price>450</Price>
</LinkedHashMap>
```

What I want is

```
<flight>
     <flightnumber>001</flightnumber>
     <Price>450</Price>
</flight>
```

Is there any to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a POJO describing the structure you want. Something like this:

```
public class Flight {

    private Integer flightNumber;
    private Double price;

    public Flight() {
    }

    public Integer getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }

    public void setFlightNumber(Integer flightNumber) {
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Then in your response:

```
...
Flight flight = new Flight()
flight.setFlightNumber(123);
flight.setPrice(450,99);
return new ResponseEntity(flight, httpStatus.OK);
```